# Create a file in a zip archive using stream wrapper

Tags: php, zip

I want to use a zip stream wrapper in PHP to create zip file or add files in a zip archive. Here are my example :

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('zip://file.zip#existing_file.txt');
file_put_contents('zip://file.zip#new_file.txt', 'Trying to put some stuff here...');
echo file_get_contents('zip://file.zip#new_file.txt');
```

This code gets me this output :

```
$ php test.php 
Hey, I'm an existing text in a file in a zip archive !

Warning: file_put_contents(zip://file.zip#new_file.txt): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/sylvain/test.php on line 7

Warning: file_get_contents(zip://file.zip#new_file.txt): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/sylvain/test.php on line 9
```

I get the same error when the zip file just doesn't exist.

Here are the file permissions :

```
$ ls -la
total 24
drwxrwxrwx   2 sylvain sylvain  4096 2009-11-13 14:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 134 sylvain sylvain 12288 2009-11-13 14:44 ..
-rwxrwxrwx   1 sylvain sylvain   236 2009-11-13 14:44 file.zip
-rwxrwxrwx   1 sylvain sylvain   268 2009-11-13 14:44 test.php
```

---

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do without creating a new stream wrapper ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip://` stream wrapper does not support writes: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php

Besides, Zip archives cannot be written in a stream because the CRC comes before the compressed data

Comment: According to zip file specifications http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT, CRC can be added after compressed data.

Comment: Still means that if you can't seek in a stream you won't be able to use this compression